# Changing background image based on local time

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've been trying to figure this out for over 4 hours, none of the questions (that have already been answered) in stack work for me, here's the code:

```html
<html>
<head>
  <style>
    .day {
      background-image: url(test2.png);
    }
    
    .night {
      background-image: url(test.png);
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body class="day" class="night">
  <script>
    setInterval(function() {
      var d = new Date();
      var n = d.getHours();
      if (n > 23 || n < 6) {
        document.body.className = "night";
      } else {
        document.body.className = "day";
      }
      console.log("test");
    }, 1000 * 60 * 60);
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I want the night background to be from 11PM to 7AM, and the rest of the time for the day background.

As you might see, those test.png pictures are changed instead of original so you don't see the pictures I want, since they contain minor gore, feel free to put your own test images in them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your logic is perfect and works as intended (I changed the images to colours, because StackOverflow gave an error when I tried your snippet).

The only problem (to you a problem, to others a design feature) is that setInterval starts after the first interval is complete. In other words; you had to wait an hour to see the results.

In my fix I moved the JavaScript to a separate function, which is mentioned by the `setInterval` and after that immediately called.

I also removed the double classes on the body, because that will be set by the function.

Edit: I forgot to mention that a double class (`day` and `night`) can occur with this code. You should write some logic to remove `day` when `night` is applied and vice versa.

Edit2: I changed the equation for the time a bit. `n` can't be bigger than 23, but it can be 23. Also, you wanted to change it to day around 7, which includes 6. So your equation should be right.

As user [Salman A](https://stackoverflow.com/users/87015/salman-a) states, you should decrease the interval. If a user starts browsing your site at 6:58 and stayed one a single page for an hour (I don't know the business of your website, but that's quite long), the background would change around 7:58. So decrease your interval to something like 1 or 2 minutes (`1000 * 60  * 1` or `1000 * 60 * 2`).

```html
<html>
<head>
  <style>
    .day {
      background-color: #ccc;
    }
    
    .night {
      background-color: #333;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <script>
    setInterval(change_background, 1000 * 60 * 60);

    function change_background() {
      var d = new Date();
      var n = d.getHours();
      console.log(n);
      if (n == 23 || n < 7) {
        document.body.className = "night";
      } else {
        document.body.className = "day";
      }
      console.log("test");
    }

    change_background();
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Might as well add that it should be >= 23 or <= 6.

Comment: @SalmanA >= 23 or <= 7, according to his post. Right? Or am I thinking wrong now?

Comment: What does n > 23 mean? Can n be 24? And n < 6 means 5 or less.

Comment: No, `n` can't be 24. You're right. It's late already over here, let me change my answer!

Comment: And interval should be smaller, like 1 minute. Otherwise if the user opens the page at 11:00:00.001PM he'll have to wait for 1 hour for the page to update.